# android studio fragments and support libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

the problem is that  when i start my project using a built in navigation drawer activity(and also fullscreen Activity) It works with components from android support v7&4,But when I added a fragment to the main Activity it doesn't  work though the min sdk is  16.
I didn't change any file of gradle files.
[error while building image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBE6y.png)
thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add dependencies in gradle.build

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
```